# Android AppBarLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-appcompat, statusbar, appbar

[image: This is what I want]

[image: This is what it looks like]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uohbn.png) is what I want to archive, but what it looks like atm is [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJaA6.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="Edit Profile"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
          .....
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried almost every solution on Stack Overflow,

e.g.

`fitsSystemWindows="true"`

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`

and many more..

I don't think it should be this difficult.
Any suggestions or example projects are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing all `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`?

Comment: Try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout` only.

Comment: I tried removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from both, and from `CoordinatorLayout` only, and `AppBarLayout` only, all combinations didn't have any effect on the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, but I don't know how.

I tried all the possible `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
combinations before but none of the combination worked, but after I changed bunch of layouts, it's just suddenly fixed.

I tracked down every single lines of code changes,
and it turned out I should remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` option from the `AppBarLayout`.

It's really weird because I tried exactly the same thing about 3 times before, but it didn't have any effect on the layout.

I think it's probably a caching issue or some bug on annoying Android Studio again..

If anyone suffer from similar issues with me, I would recommend 

`1. clean project
2. remove the layout entirely and put it back`

to see the actual changes

I wasted about 5 hours on this problem and the lesson is just
"don't trust Android Studio"

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian I had the same problem before , after playing around with fitssystemwindows attribute , it was fixed. I don't exactly remember what I had done , don't even know what that attribute does . So you can try different combinations adding/removing fitssystemwindows too. For example , remove it from appbarlayout and see what happens.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations, and changing `fitssystemwindows` attribute has no effect on layout at all.

Comment: does your nestedscroll has any more attributes ? can you post them

Comment: nope nestedscroll only has those attributes in the question.